Значение одной ячейки JTable дублируется во все после ввода
У меня есть программа, в которой на данный момент реализован функционал добавления и удаления столбцов таблицы, но есть одна проблема, при вводе значений в эту таблицу они начинают дублироваться в других ячейках:
Ввожу значение в одну ячейку: 
Дальше нажимаю enter, чтобы перестать редактировать ячейку и каким-то магическим образом все ячейки слева от этой заполняются такими же значениями: 
Если я нажимаю на любую ячейку справа от этой, то такими же значениями заполняются все ячейки между первоначальной и нажатой, включая её: 
Если я взаимодействую с кнопкой для перемещения по строке ячеек, то заполняются вообще все ячейки одинаковыми значениями.
Код:
package ru.kirill.task9;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

import ru.kirill.addition.Addition;


public class GraphicApp {
    private boolean isReverse = false;

    class MainFrame extends JFrame {
        private static final String TITLE = "Главное меню";
        private static final String MINUS = "-";
        private static final String PLUS = "+";
        private static final String OPEN_BUTTON_TEXT = "Открыть";
        private static final String SAVE_BUTTON_TEXT = "Сохранить";
        private static final String REVERSE_BUTTON_TEXT = "Перевернуть";
        private static final String ENTER_LABEL_TITLE = "Количество элементов";
        private static final String CALCULATE_BUTTON_TEXT = "Рассчитать";
        private static final String REFRESH_BUTTON_TEXT = "Обновить";

        JButton minusButton;
        JButton refreshButton;
        JButton plusButton;
        JButton openButton;
        JButton saveButton;
        JButton reverseButton;
        JButton calculateButton;
        JTable inputTable;
        JTable outputTable;
        JLabel titleOfEnterQuantityElements;
        JTextField fieldOfEnterQuantityElements;


        MainFrame() {
            super(TITLE);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            createMainFrameLayout();

            minusButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int numberOfCells = Integer.parseInt(fieldOfEnterQuantityElements.getText());
                    if (numberOfCells > 1) {
                        fieldOfEnterQuantityElements.setText(
                            Integer.toString(
                                numberOfCells - 1));
                    }
                }
            });

            refreshButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int numberOfCells = 1;
                    try {
                        numberOfCells = Integer.parseInt(fieldOfEnterQuantityElements.getText());
                    } catch (NumberFormatException err) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                                      "Вы ввели неверное значение");
                        fieldOfEnterQuantityElements.setText("1");
                    }
                    int columnCount = inputTable.getColumnCount();
                    if (numberOfCells < 1) {
                        numberOfCells = 1;
                        fieldOfEnterQuantityElements.setText("1");
                    }
                    if (numberOfCells < columnCount) {
                        TableColumnModel inputTableModel = inputTable.getColumnModel();
                        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount - numberOfCells; i++) {
                            inputTable.removeColumn(inputTableModel.getColumn(columnCount - i - 1));
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCells - columnCount; i++) {
                            TableColumn newColumn = new TableColumn();
                            newColumn.setCellRenderer(new CustomCellRenderer());
                            newColumn.setCellEditor(new CustomCellEditor(new JTextField()));
                            inputTable.addColumn(newColumn);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            plusButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    fieldOfEnterQuantityElements.setText(
                        Integer.toString(
                            Integer.parseInt(fieldOfEnterQuantityElements.getText()) + 1));
                }
            });

            pack();
            setSize(600, 285);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setResizable(false);
            setVisible(true);

            calculateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < inputTable.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                        System.out.print(inputTable.getValueAt(0, i));
                    }
                }
            });
        }


        private void createMainFrameLayout() {
            Container pane = getContentPane();
            pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints layout = new GridBagConstraints();

            JPanel topInteractionPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            topInteractionPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            layout.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            layout.weightx = 1;
            layout.weighty = 0.15;
            layout.gridx = 0;
            layout.gridy = 0;
            layout.gridwidth = 1;
            layout.gridheight = 1;
            pane.add(topInteractionPanel, layout);

            minusButton = new JButton(MINUS);
            layout.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            layout.weightx = 0.1;
            layout.weighty = 1;
            layout.gridx = 0;
            layout.gridy = 0;
            layout.gridwidth = 1;
            layout.gridheight = 1;
            topInteractionPanel.add(minusButton, layout);

            JPanel enterQuantityElementsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            layout.weightx = 0.8;
            layout.weighty = 1;
            layout.gridx = 1;
            layout.gridy = 0;
            layout.gridwidth = 1;
            layout.gridheight = 1;
            topInteractionPanel.add(enterQuantityElementsPanel, layout);

            titleOfEnterQuantityElements = new JLabel(ENTER_LABEL_TITLE);
            layout.weightx = 1;
            layout.weighty = 0.5;
            layout.gridx = 0;
            layout.gridy = 0;
            layout.gridwidth = 1;
            layout.gridheight = 1;
            enterQuantityElementsPanel.add(titleOfEnterQuantityElements, layout);

            JPanel enterTextFieldPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            layout.weightx = 1;
            layout.weighty = 0.5;
            layout.gridx = 0;
            layout.gridy = 1;
            layout.gridwidth = 1;
            layout.gridheight = 1;
            enterQuantityElementsPanel.add(enterTextFieldPanel, layout);

            fieldOfEnterQuantityElements = new JTextField();
            fieldOfEnterQuantityElements.setText("1");
            layout.weightx = 0.7;
            layout.weighty = 1;
            layout.gridx = 0;
            layout.gridy = 0;
            layout.gridwidth = 1;
            layout.gridheight = 1;
            enterTextFieldPanel.add(fieldOfEnterQuantityElements, layout);

            refreshButton = new JButton(REFRESH_BUTTON_TEXT);
            layout.weightx = 0.3;
            layout.weighty = 1;
            layout.gridx = 1;
            layout.gridy = 0;
            layout.gridwidth = 1;
            layout.gridheight = 1;
            enterTextFieldPanel.add(refreshButton, layout);

            plusButton = new JButton(PLUS);
            layout.weightx = 0.1;
            layout.weighty = 1;
            layout.gridx = 2;
            layout.gridy = 0;
            layout.gridwidth = 1;
            layout.gridheight = 1;
            topInteractionPanel.add(plusButton, layout);


            JPanel inputTablePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            inputTablePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            layout.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            layout.weightx = 1;
            layout.weighty = 0.30;
            layout.gridx = 0;
            layout.gridy = 1;
            layout.gridwidth = 1;
            layout.gridheight = 1;
            pane.add(inputTablePanel, layout);

            inputTable = new JTable(1, 1);
            TableColumnModel inputTableModel = inputTable.getColumnModel();
            TableColumn firstColumn = new TableColumn();
            firstColumn.setCellRenderer(new CustomCellRenderer());
            firstColumn.setCellEditor(new CustomCellEditor(new JTextField()));
            inputTableModel.addColumn(firstColumn);
            inputTableModel.removeColumn(inputTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0));
            inputTable.setTableHeader(null);
            inputTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
            inputTable.setRowHeight(50);
            JScrollPane inputScrollPane = new JScrollPane(inputTable);
            layout.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            layout.weightx = 1;
            layout.weighty = 1;
            layout.gridx = 0;
            layout.gridy = 0;
            layout.gridwidth = 1;
            layout.gridheight = 1;
            inputTablePanel.add(inputScrollPane, layout);


            JPanel bottomInteractionPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            bottomInteractionPanel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
            layout.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            layout.weightx = 1;
            layout.weighty = 0.15;
            layout.gridx = 0;
            layout.gridy = 2;
            layout.gridwidth = 1;
            layout.gridheight = 1;
            pane.add(bottomInteractionPanel, layout);

            openButton = new JButton(OPEN_BUTTON_TEXT);
            layout.weightx = 0.25;
            layout.weighty = 1;
            layout.gridx = 0;
            layout.gridy = 0;
            layout.gridwidth = 1;
            layout.gridheight = 1;
            bottomInteractionPanel.add(openButton, layout);

            saveButton = new JButton(SAVE_BUTTON_TEXT);
            layout.weightx = 0.25;
            layout.weighty = 1;
            layout.gridx = 1;
            layout.gridy = 0;
            layout.gridwidth = 1;
            layout.gridheight = 1;
            bottomInteractionPanel.add(saveButton, layout);

            reverseButton = new JButton(REVERSE_BUTTON_TEXT);
            layout.weightx = 0.25;
            layout.weighty = 1;
            layout.gridx = 2;
            layout.gridy = 0;
            layout.gridwidth = 1;
            layout.gridheight = 1;
            bottomInteractionPanel.add(reverseButton, layout);

            calculateButton = new JButton(CALCULATE_BUTTON_TEXT);
            layout.weightx = 0.25;
            layout.weighty = 1;
            layout.gridx = 3;
            layout.gridy = 0;
            layout.gridwidth = 1;
            layout.gridheight = 1;
            bottomInteractionPanel.add(calculateButton, layout);


            JPanel outputTablePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            outputTablePanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
            layout.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            layout.weightx = 1;
            layout.weighty = 0.30;
            layout.gridx = 0;
            layout.gridy = 3;
            layout.gridwidth = 1;
            layout.gridheight = 1;
            pane.add(outputTablePanel, layout);

            outputTable = new JTable(1, 1);
            outputTable.setTableHeader(null);
            outputTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
            outputTable.setRowHeight(50);
            outputTable.setEnabled(false);
            JScrollPane outputScrollPane = new JScrollPane(outputTable);
            layout.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            layout.weightx = 1;
            layout.weighty = 1;
            layout.gridx = 0;
            layout.gridy = 0;
            layout.gridwidth = 1;
            layout.gridheight = 1;
            outputTablePanel.add(outputScrollPane, layout);
        }


        class CustomCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
            public CustomCellEditor(JTextField textField) {
                super(textField);
                this.clickCountToStart = 1;
            }
        }


        class CustomCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                                           boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                                                           int row, int column) {
                setFont(table.getFont());
                setValue(value);
                return this;
            }
        }
    }


    public GraphicApp() {
        new MainFrame();
    }
    public GraphicApp(boolean isReverse) {
        this.isReverse = isReverse;
        new MainFrame();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GraphicApp();
    }
}


Как мне убрать это автозаполнение, чтобы всё работало нормально?

Я смог решить свою проблему тем, что стал использовать в качестве модели таблицы DefaultTableModel
inputTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new String[1], 1);
inputTable = new JTable(inputTableModel);
inputTable.setDefaultRenderer(
    Object.class, new CustomCellRenderer());
inputTable.setDefaultEditor(
    Object.class, new CustomCellEditor(new JTextField()));
inputTable.setTableHeader(null);
inputTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
inputTable.setRowHeight(50);
JScrollPane inputScrollPane = new JScrollPane(inputTable);
layout.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
layout.weightx = 1;
layout.weighty = 1;
layout.gridx = 0;
layout.gridy = 0;
layout.gridwidth = 1;
layout.gridheight = 1;
inputTablePanel.add(inputScrollPane, layout);

